# Alternative to individual worksheetfunction.match-es for worksheet updates with different column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really just looking for an example to get me started on this, and all of my searches lead to results involving copying and pasting a whole row/column.

I have two workbooks, and a colleague will be updating one of them sporadically. I'd like to create a command button that will update the differences between the two sheets. I'll have them both open, so no need to open/save/close. The data are set up as a list of people with attributes (email, phone, etc.) in columns to the right. I can use the last name as my vertical match. What I'd like to do is write some code that equivocates one column to another (e.g., "Email" = "PI Email"; "PI Last Name" = "PI (Last)") so that it's putting the correct data in the correct place. I am wanting to avoid having an individual Find or WorksheetFunction Index-Match for each column. Any ideas?

A related question is whether it will be more processor-intensive to only replace differences or replace the whole row when the first difference is found. I'm assuming that it will be faster to look for differences rather than just replace everything.

Comment: You could use `vlookup` for each attribute and index on last name. That will ensure data in one sheet is aligned to the master sheet.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this. That's really what I'm wanting to avoid, although I might just have to do that.

Comment: Other way: use concatenate function on attributes to identify any attribute change. Then simply copy that row of data into the worksheet. This way you only update what has changed.